ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic is not supported
I have a problem with updating the kernel. I managed to update it up to version 6.9.3, after that whatever version I try to load, I always have the same problem:
Building module: 
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.9.4-060904-generic KVER=6.9.4-060904-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.9.4-060904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
kernelver=6.9.4-060904-generic ./dkms-make.sh...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821au: 5.12.5.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.9.4-060904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821au/5.12.5.2/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.9.4-060904-generic -C /lib/modules/6.9.4-060904-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.16/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.9.4-060904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.16/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.9.4-060904-generic/x86_64 failed for broadcom-sta(10) rtl8821au(10) virtualbox(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.9.4-060904-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic (--install):
 il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic script post-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 11
Configurazione di linux-modules-6.9.4-060904-generic (6.9.4-060904.202408071026)...
Configurazione di linux-image-unsigned-6.9.4-060904-generic (6.9.4-060904.202408071026)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per linux-image-unsigned-6.9.4-060904-generic (6.9.4-060904.202408071026)...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.9.4-060904-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.9.4-060904-generic KVER=6.9.4-060904-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.9.4-060904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
kernelver=6.9.4-060904-generic ./dkms-make.sh...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821au: 5.12.5.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.9.4-060904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821au/5.12.5.2/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.9.4-060904-generic -C /lib/modules/6.9.4-060904-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.16/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.9.4-060904-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.9.4-060904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.16/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.9.4-060904-generic/x86_64 failed for broadcom-sta(10) rtl8821au(10) virtualbox(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.9.4-060904-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11

I have read several questions on this topic regarding old versions of ubuntu and I have seen that some people recommend to delete virtualbox-dkms, broadcom-sta-dkms and rtl8821au-dkms and install the kernel. I would prefer to avoid deleting broadcom-sta-dkms so I would like to find a way to upgrade them with the new kernel.
Can anyone help me with this?
I would not want to aggravate the situation more than I have to so I am asking you who have more experience.
Thanks

You've provided no Ubuntu product or release details, and the kernels you specifically mention are not supported Ubuntu kernels either, being testing kernels only.  What OS are you using?

Welcome to ASK.
I think you really need to treat this as three question (one for each dkms module that is suspect)
Regarding rtl8821au-dkms the following site has a version that reports it is compatible with the following kernels: -

Kernels: 5.4 - 5.11 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.12 - 6.10 (community support)

https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708

Ok, thanks a lot. I will treat these issues in three questions.
